# PHP - Paginated List on XHTML form

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, xhtml

(PHP newbie)

I am trying to extract data from my database using my select query. I can echo the information onto a different page but I want to be able to populate using a Paginated list and have that list on the same page instead of going to a different page.

How can I do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

what is the event that triggers the query?  A page load, or a submit button perhaps?  could you post some of your code and provide more detail?

If it's a php page performing a query based on form submission, then just set the action of the form equal to the page name and retrieve the POST values.  If reloading the page is not an option, then you may want to look into AJAX queries.

Comment: Isn't there a conventional way of doing this?

Comment: depends entirely on how you want your query to execute, and where the query data comes from. If it's from a form submission on the same page, then I would use ACTION='page.php' METHOD='POST' in the form tag (where page.php is the page you want the information to be displayed) and at the top of the page use the POST method to retrieve the values